# What are the key design components for illuminating Christmas lights using a PIC

Tags: mosfet, led, pic

So my cheap Christmas lights failed this year due to something broken in the control logic.  I thought I would try and build my own control circuit and use them again next year.
The LED lights still work just fine.  There are 2 sets of LEDs but wired on a single conductor. Every other LED has its polarity/direction reversed so that by switching the polarity of the input power, each set of LEDs can be illuminated independently (but only one set of LEDs can be on at any one time).

I am going to use a PIC16F1503 to control the lights, making use of the PWM module(s) to adjust the intensity of the LEDs.  I'm pretty confident I can get this working with a simple BJT transistor, with base connected to the PWM output PIC pin. I am also considering a MOSFET for this purpose.
Power to the PIC will be 5V via a USB connection.
The LED string draws around 80mA when fully on, but will usually be less due to being dimmed and/or flashing.

Where I am coming a bit unstuck is in how to switch between the 2 LED strings.  I've read about using a H bridge and understand how this works - in my case I would be switching the H bridge MOSFETs on/off using PIC pins and associated logic.

Is this a 'good' way of switching polarity, or might there be a simpler way of achieving what I need?

Comment: And what total voltage are these LED strings?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Not sure why this matters. The max voltage available will be 5V but the current through the LED string will be gated by resistor if necessary. I suspect the voltage at the LED string will need to be around 3V though.

Comment: It makes a huge difference if they are 230VAC vs. 3VDC.